# How to prevent Django from localizing IDs in templates?

Tags: django, localization, django-templates

I have recently upgraded to Django 1.2.5, and now I am having problems with localization, specifically number formatting. For example, in some templates I print the following samples:

```
data-id="{{ form.instance.id }}"
```

Which in cases >= 1000, used to evaluate to:

```
data-id="1235"
```

But now it actually results in (my localization is pt-BR, our decimal separator is dot):

```
data-id="1.235"
```

Which of course is not found when I afterwards query the database by ID. Using a `|safe` filter solves the problem, but I'm not willing to find all IDs in all templates and safe them.

Usually, I'll only localize the **floating points, not the integers**. I don't want to disable L10N, because of all the other formatting that is working fine. **Is there a way to make this distinction in Django localization?** Any other solution is accepted.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Don At the time, I was forced to disable USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR (as I mentioned below in #comment6697430_5826535). Ultimately, the Django template system will always try to format ints, so you can't globally disable that.

Answer (score 13):

```
data-id="{{ form.instance.id|safe }}"
```

Also do the job

Answer (score 9):

with django 1.2:

```
data-id="{{ form.instance.id|stringformat:'d' }}"
```

or, with django 1.3:

```
{% load l10n %}

{% localize off %}
    data-id="{{ form.instance.id|stringformat:'d' }}"
{% endlocalize %}
```

or (also with django 1.3):

```
data-id="{{ form.instance.id|unlocalize }}"
```

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#topic-l10n-templates
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat

Comment: It works, as well as `|safe` as I mentioned, but I was looking for a way not to need to treat every id output. I had to temporarily disable USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR, but it also disables floating points.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question but check out this section of the [**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#topic-l10n-templates). It says to use `{{ |unlocalize }}` filter or:

```
{% localize on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocalize %}

{% localize off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

There's probably a better way but I'm thinking that you could write a method that gives you the id as a string in your model for each model you are trying to display the id in a template.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

    def str_id(self):
        return u'%s' % self.id
```

in your template:

```
{{ form.instance.str_id }}
```